# How to stop firefox from mangling domain names?

Tags: firefox, url, domain-name, about-config

When I type in `http://example/` firefox rewites the url to `http://www.example.com/`.  Is there any way to fix this behavior without recompiling firefox?  I suspect something in `about:config` will help, but I am not sure what, and I'm somewhat leery of randomly changing things just to see if they have the effect I want.

#### Edit:

What I would like is for firefox to try to make a http request to `example` (which it does, usually finding the address my `etc/hosts` file provides) and then, if unable to connect, to fail with a "could not connect" error, with `example` still in the address bar.  Its current behavior is to then try to look up `www.example.com`, which tends to result in a 'valid' site, and I get a screen full of some domain squatter's dross and have to remove the `www.` and `.com` from the address before I can fix my typo.

Comment: So what **is** the effect you want?

Comment: I'm able to get firefox to give me an error, mind posting your hosts file?

Comment: Mozilla calls this "domain guessing", so perhaps someone with sufficient reputation (or the OP) could add that tag.

Comment: @JohnT, check `browser.fixup.*`? that seems to be the right place for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to set **browser.fixup.alternate.enabled** and perhaps **keyword.enabled** to false. See also [this article](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/domain-guessing.html) and the [about:config docs.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

(Note: untested.)

Comment: `browser.fixup.*` = `false` or `""` did it, thanks